# Is it possible to only update 64 bit applications when both 64/32 bit architecture enabled?

Tags: apt, kali-linux, 32bit

I'm using 64 bit Kali Linux, the 32 bit architecture is enabled only for running games with Wine. Every time update package via `apt update`, it checks both 32/64 bit like:

```
...
Get:12 ... kali-rolling/main i386 Packages [17.7 MB]
Get:13 ... kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages [17.8 MB]
Get:14 ... kali-rolling/main i386 Contents (deb) [39.3 MB]
Get:15 ... kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb) [39.7 MB]
...
```

My */etc/apt/sources.list*:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

It downloads about 60Mb contents for checking 32bit, which is unnecessary as long as the game runs fine. My network is slow, so download 60Mb takes some time, is it possible to make it only check for 64 bit or check the 32 bit when I need to?

Comment: why would you run games in kali? ... kali is not a general linux distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *possible*, by disabling `i386`:

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture --remove-architecture i386
```

This won’t remove your 32-bit packages, but it will cause `apt` to stop updating the corresponding indexes.

**However** this is liable to cause problems because 32- and 64-bit versions of packages need to be kept in sync.

To update 64-bit packages again, add the architecture back with

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```